# Python - When importing a function python runs that file prior to the one I am running

Tags: python, import

So I have 2 files. Coinvalues.py which has a bunch of functions in it that I want to use but it is also a standalone program that does things.

In my second file called GUI.py it will look up data and display it in a GUI.

I am trying to pull functions from Coinvalues.py using

```
from Coinvalues import USDValue, SATValue, BTCValue
```

But once I run the program GUI.py it runs Coinvalues.py in its entirety then it starts GUI.py. I just want to take the few functions from Coinvalues without it doing this. Is this built into python like this or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately **those functions do not exist unless the other file is executed**. There is no way around this. You can, however, use a [main sentinel](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) in order to prevent execution of specific blocks of code when a file is imported.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. I'll just make a seperate file and throw all of the functions in there. I'll pull what I need to run Coinvalues by itself. Thank you!

Comment: Using the main sentinel is the standard way to go.

Comment: While that may be I plan on using these for multiple programs so I think it will be in my best interest to just make a separate library for all of the functions I have. Thanks though!